# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle; certain intersection has to be empty

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $S$ be a multi-set with k distinct different elements with given repetition numbers $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ respectively. Let $r$ be a positive integer such that there exists at least one $r$-combination of the set $S$. Show that in applying the inclusion-exclusion principle to determine the number of $r$-combinations of the set $S$, one has $A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_k=\varnothing$.

What I've done so far is noticed that since there exists one integer $r$ such that there is at least one $r$-combination of the set $S$, then $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\ge k$. Also notice that each $n_i\ge1$. I can see that if one of those $n_i$ is $2$ or more, then I can see that the proposition is true. However what I'm having trouble with is the case when $n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k=r$, because in this case $A_1\cap A_2\ldots\cap A_k=1$, correct? I'm unsure of how to proceed with this this proof any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are the sets $A_i$? How can their intersection be $1$? Do you mean that $|A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_k|=1$?

Comment: The sets $A_i$ are the sets such that there are $n_i$ of the i'th element of the set S.  Their intersection can be 1 when $n_1$+$n_2$+...+$n_i$=r right?

Comment: And yes I do mean $|A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_k|=1$

Comment: I’m afraid that this is still pretty opaque: you’re assuming that we know context that you haven’t given us. What is an $r$-combination of the set $S$? Is it a multiset of cardinality $r$ that is a subset of $S$? If so, the existence of an $r$-combination implies that $\sum_in_i\ge r$, not that $\sum_in_i\ge k$. And you still haven’t actually said clearly what the sets $A_i$ are. Do you mean that $A_i$ is the collection of all $r$-multisubsets of $S$ containing all $n_i$ copies of the $i$-th element of $S$?

Comment: An r-combination of the set S is the number of ways to permute the set S which is a multi set of cardinality $n_1$+$n_2$+...$n_k$ where each $n_k$ is the repetition numbers of each element respectively such that order doesn't matter. Also that is what I mean for each $A_i$

Comment: If you’re *permuting* something, by definition order *does* matter. I’ll try one more time. Is your definition of $r$-combination the same as the one at the beginning of [this PDF](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~sokratov/2008m150/multicomb.pdf)?

Comment: Ah yeah didnt mean to use the word permute, and yes that is my definition of an r-combination.

Answer (score 0):

From "there is at least one r-combination of S", we can see that r is smaller or equal to n1 + n2 + ... + nk. When trying to figure out the cases of all the intersections, we need to assume there're n1+1, n2+1, ..., nk+1 elements respectively, which is clearly bigger than r. Hence, the intersection is the empty set.